# How to check that a string can be cast to a custom type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, casting

I'm new in Typescript and I have the following types and interface for a sudoku game :

```
export type GridCellValue = 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9;

export interface GridCell {
  readonly: boolean,
  value: GridCellValue|null,
}

export type Grid = Array<Array<GridCell>>
```

The cells in the sudoku grid are `HTMLInputElement`s that trigger an `InputEvent` when their input changes (`Vue`'s `@input` directive).

My validation function is as follows :

```
function validate_input(ev: InputEvent) {
  const input_string: string = ev.data ?? '';
  const grid_cell_value_regex = /^([123456789])$/;
  const value = grid_cell_value_regex.test(input_string) ? input_string : '';
  if (ev.target === null)
    return;
  const el = ev.target as HTMLInputElement;
  el.value = value;
}
```

What I want is a better way to check that `input_string` can be cast to `GridCellValue`, without having to resort to using Regex, is this possible?

I tried using `instanceof` and `is` to check but it didn't work.

Comment: To help you find a better solution, it would be helpful to know what your issue with a regular expression is. `/^[1-9]$/` is a bit shorter btw.

Comment: In this exact use case, it's true that a regex is sufficient, but I imagine if the type was complicated, it'd be difficult to have a regex for it. Also, if for some reason in the future I change the definition of the type, I'm also obligated to change the regex in another file, which seems like an error prone approach.

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer because it's situational to what kind of strings you want to accept and what sort of pattern there is. And yeah if you have a function that parses these strings,  write it once and import it anywhere you need it. Dont copy it

Comment: The important thing to remember is that Typescript types only exist at "compile time", so if you need to check at runtime if a value can be assigned to a Typescript type, you always need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a type-narrowing function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) (also known as a "type guard") combined with `valueAsNumber` (which does the parsing for you) combined with a range-check, like so:

```js
function onInputInput( ev: InputEvent ): void {
    
    const value = (ev.sender as HTMLInputElement).valueAsNumber;
    if( isGridCellValue( value ) ) {
        // do stuff here: TSC will narrow `value` to `GridCellValue` within the scope of this `if` statement's block.
    }
}

function isGridCellValue( value: number ): value is GridCellValue {

    return (
        Math.floor( value ) === value
        &&
        value >= 1
        &&
        value <= 9
    );
}
```